# different behaviour between gdb and lldb debugger

Tags: objective-c, gdb, lldb

I am loading an array of friends and passing it to my uitableview, every thing is working but when i put a break point in the method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:             (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

with the gdb debugger I can see the content of my friends NSMutableArray and with the lldb it says the friends array has zero objects yet it works as expected and all my friends are showing... as Apple recommended using the lldb how do you debug with it? as it's not even showing the content of my objects... plus if you have console commands/tips you use for debugging with gdb/lldb would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your compiler. I would recommend using the **lldb** debugger with the "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0", and **gdb** for GCC flavors (including "LLVM GCC 4.2").

Here are some links I have found useful for debugging:

- http://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2007/10/instruments-on-leopard-how-to-debug-those-random-crashes-in-your-cocoa-app/
- http://www.markj.net/iphone-memory-debug-nszombie/
- http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DebuggingAutorelease

Best regards,
David